# More granularity needed in Publish CV options

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

I'd like to be able to include employer and job titles in the experience section of my Public CV without also including all the detailed job duties. It seems like adding one more level of granularity in that hierarchy should be straightforward.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll add this - we were just waiting to see if anyone wanted it :)



**Update - now live**

You can set the visibility on the large textarea descriptions of any Experience and Education sections.

Comment: @hemp No problem - I can add toggling to the other Experience/Education fields easily enough, but I'm not sure if there's a real need.